# Capitalise and Sort in Python

Tags: python, csv, sorting, alphabetic

I have created a small function that sorts the rows in a CSV File alphabetically. However, it sorts them capitalised vs not capitalised. Is there anyway to capitalise all of the entries and then sort them ?

```
import csv

def CSV_alphabetisch():
    try: 
        reader = csv.reader(open("G.csv"), delimiter=";")
        sortedlist = sorted(reader,)
        with open ("G.csv","w") as new:
          writer = csv.writer(new,delimiter=";")
          for n in sortedlist:
            writer.writerows([n])
    except IndexError:
        print ("Index Error")
CSV_alphabetisch()
```

I have tried using the .capitalise() function, but I unfortunately get an error message. I would appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: "An" error message? Posting the full traceback will help us help you. Make sure to post that non-working code as there is no `capitalize` in your sample.

Comment: sortedlist = sorted(reader, key=lambda s: s.capitalize())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'capitalize'

Comment: You can use [edit] your question instead of burying it into a comment.

Comment: oops, sorry, I missed that function. Thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean: `'string'.capitalize()`? (with a 'z')

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that is what I meant.